# Python 3.10 - error : 'cookielib' is not defined. Did you mean: 'CookieJar'?

Tags: python

Think I've been looking at this too long.  But I'm trying to scrape a website using Python 3.10  Before I do that I need to login and this is my code:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

try:
    from http.cookiejar import CookieJar
except ImportError:
    from cookielib import CookieJar

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("https://mywebsite.com")

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['username'] = 'xxxxxxxxxx@test.com'
br.form['password'] = 'top_secret_password'
br.submit()

print (br.response().read())
```

I know that cookielib got replaced with cookiejar.  When I run the below I keep receiving the error:

```
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
NameError: name 'cookielib' is not defined. Did you mean: 'CookieJar'?
```

where am I going wrong?  I have a Try to import CookieJar

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `from http.cookiejar import CookieJar` means? After that succeeds, how do you expect that you should access the imported thing - by writing `http.cookiejar.CookieJar`, or by writing `CookieJar`? Same question for the fallback import. Do you understand what the `from` style of importing is for? Where the error message says `Did you mean: 'CookieJar'?`, was that unclear? Did you try writing just `cj = CookieJar()`? Why not?

Comment: good point, thank you.  I've just started out with Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `from`, you're directly importing the name `CookieJar` from either `http.cookiejar` or `cookielib`. Regardless, the line `cj = cookielib.CookieJar()` would never work, because you've not imported the name `cookielib` in either case. You just need to do `cj = CookieJar()`.